# After windows update ran this morning, PC boots to black screen

Tags: windows-8.1

I am running Windows 8.1, and this morning I was prompted to reboot. I have been putting it off for a few days and it would no longer allow me to postpone. I restarted adding the updates and now when I boot I get nothing but a black screen. I can get to the bios, but not safe mode / windows recovery screen. The windows logo never comes up and hitting F8 nor shift + F8 does anything, due to the fact that I don't think windows exists in a non-corrupted state.

Is there anything I can do, other than going to someone else's house / computer and creating a boot disk / flash drive?

Comment: Use the Windows [recovery disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive) you didn't bother to make. ;)

Comment: Yes the problem now is getting somewhere I can create it. iPhones don't have a USB drive lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all, try running Windows in safe mode see more about

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm

After you boot in safe mode, Windows should load the default drivers for the video card.

If Windows is running in safe mode, you have a driver issue. You can try this driver
 - http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/73218

not sure if it will work...